# Popup in Browser based - InfoPath forms - SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, browser-enabled-form

I am working on InfoPath browser-based forms - SharePoint Online.

I have 2 questions (type Yes/No) in a section on the form and if the user selects Yes for any of these questions a popup must be displayed to the user. The pop up contains terms and conditions.

I understand that Popups are not available out of the box in browser based forms correct me if I am wrong. I am not interested in writing code.

As an alternative, I planned to change views when the user selects yes, but there is no option to switch views on checkboxes. I can do this using button only. But I do not need a button as per my requirement.

What would be the best solution to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a view change, you can insert a section into the form and place your T&C text into that section. Use formatting rules for the section to hide it when the two checkboxes have the unticked value or are empty. As soon as one of the boxes are ticked, the section will show.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Hide/show section works well but I want the section to appear after both the questions are answered. As you mentioned, with section show/hide when one of the question is answered Yes section appears.

Comment: Your question states differently: `if the user selects Yes for any of these questions`. Of course you can set a rule that unhides the section only when both boxes are ticked.